# Is Scrapy single-threaded or multi-threaded?

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, web-crawler

There are few concurrency settings in Scrapy, like [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests). Does it mean, that Scrapy crawler is multi-threaded? So if I run `scrapy crawl my_crawler` it will literally fire multiple simultaneous requests in parallel? 
Im asking because, I've read that Scrapy is single-threaded.

Comment: Scrapy uses Twisted, and uses a single-threaded asynchronous programming model. You can read about it [in](http://krondo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/twisted-intro.html) [various](http://krondo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/twisted-intro.html) [places](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/11/twisted-hello-asynchronous-programming)

Answer (score 16):

Scrapy is single-threaded, except the interactive shell and some tests, see [source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/search?q=thread&type=Code).

It's built on top of [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation), which is single-threaded too, and makes use of it's own asynchronous concurrency capabilities, such as [`twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.callFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.html#callFromThread), see [source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/search?q=callFromThread&type=Code).

Comment: Asynchronicity means there can be multiple concurrent requests. You can send a request A, and before it has returned you make another request B, so you have two parallel requests.

Comment: I was trying to write the results of my scraping into a single text file. I know understand that that is a bad thing...or is it?

Answer (score 8):

Scrapy does most of it's work synchronously. However, the handling of requests is done asynchronously.

I suggest this page if you haven't already seen it.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html

edit:
I realize now the question was about threading and not necessarily whether it's asynchronous or not. That link would still be a good read though :)

regarding your question about CONCURRENT_REQUESTS. This setting changes the number of requests that twisted will defer at once. Once that many requests have been started it will wait for some of them to finish before starting more.

Answer (score 4):

Scrapy is single-threaded framework, we cannot use multiple threads within a spider at the same time. However, we can create multiple spiders and piplines at the same time to make the process concurrent.
Scrapy does not support `multi-threading` because it is built on `Twisted`, which is an `Asynchronous http protocol framework`.

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy is a single-threaded framework, But we can use **Multiple threads** within a spider at the same time.

please read this article.

[https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-run-scrapy-spiders-in-your-program-7db56792c1f7#:~:text=We%20use%20the%20CrawlerProcess%20class,custom%20settings%20for%20the%20Spider](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-run-scrapy-spiders-in-your-program-7db56792c1f7#:%7E:text=We%20use%20the%20CrawlerProcess%20class,custom%20settings%20for%20the%20Spider)

We can use subprocess to run spiders.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["scrapy", "crawl", "quotes", "-o", "quotes_all.json"])
```

or

Use **CrawlerProcess** to run multiple spiders in the same process.

If you want to run multiple spiders per process or want to fetch and use the scraped items directly in your program, you would need to use the internal API of Scrapy.

```
    # Run the spider with the internal API of Scrapy:
    from scrapy.crawler import Crawler, CrawlerProcess
    from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def crawler_func(spider, url):
    crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    crawler_process.crawl(spider, url)
    crawler_process.start()

def start_spider(spider, urls):
      p = multiprocessing.Pool(100)
      return p.map(partial(crawler_func, spider), urls)
```