# Why item processing in Scrapy pipeline is not concurrent?

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I make pipeline works asynchronously? I thought it's already so, because of CONCURRENT_ITEMS description:

> Maximum number of concurrent items (per response) to process in
>   parallel in the Item Processor (also known as the Item Pipeline).

Here is my pipeline:

```
class TestPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.x += 1
        log.msg(str(self.x))
        sleep(2)
        return item
```

Log:

```
2014-10-10 17:34:55+0300 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: TestPipeline
2014-10-10 17:34:55+0300 [myspider] INFO: Spider opened
2014-10-10 17:34:55+0300 [myspider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-10-10 17:34:56+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 1
2014-10-10 17:34:58+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 2
2014-10-10 17:35:00+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 3
2014-10-10 17:35:02+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 4
2014-10-10 17:35:04+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 5
2014-10-10 17:35:06+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 6
2014-10-10 17:35:08+0300 [scrapy] INFO: 7
```

My spider:

```
class myspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "example.com"
    ]

    rules = (
    ...
    )


    def __init__(self, name=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        log.start()


    def parse_page(self, response):
        links = response.xpath(some xpath)

        for link in links:
            item = Item()
            try:
                (item['url'], item['filename']) = link.re(some regex)
            except ValueError:
                continue

            yield item
```

Comment: Please show your spider implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Note that [Scrapy is single-threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761074/is-scrapy-single-threaded-or-multi-threaded), and `sleep(2)` will block the thread for 2 seconds for everything

Comment: @paultrmbrth I'm profiling another pipeline with the time consuming functions which has ~17 items per minute (that's bad), so I think there are no parallel processing in item pipelines

Comment: Hi, do you know the answer now?

Comment: @panda0 thanks for waiting. Yep, from that time I got some knowledge of python architecture. 
tl;dr scrapy is asyncronous (thanks for twisted), but my code was not - when python's single thread had been blocked by my code, scrapy cannot proceed further. As a solution I moved my blocking code (with syncronous requests) to Celery. If this answer isn't enough - ping me out, I'll write down a detailed version